# How to configure/format spagobi export to excel configuration

Tags: excel, birt, spagobi

I have a problem with exporting to excel.
When I open a birt report here is a option to export to a excel:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a0nR.png

But here is a result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMbNv.png

How I can remove this formating from excel?

Is there any way to configure excel export engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered your post on http://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/3440.page
I'm answering here as well, so it might help other people .

I ran into this exact problem. I tried a different Excel emitter for BIRT, called Spudsoft BIRT Excel emitter. I plugged this into BIRT / SpagoBI Server and Studio.   This helped the the following

It removed the empty, hidden rows and columns in the Excel output 
It allowed better control over whether all the output goes on one Excel tab or whether it paginates over multiple tabs

Spudsoft BIRT Excel emitter: https://bitbucket.org/yaytay/spudsoft-birt-excel-emitters/downloads

**Steps to use the spudsoft emitter in SpagoBI server**

1. Download the uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.source_0.8.0.201310230652 jar file.
2. Place the jar file in the SpagoBI\webapps\SpagoBIBirtReportEngine\WEB-INF\lib
3. Take the jar files present in uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel_0.8.0.201310230652\lib (found after unzipping the emitter jar file) and place them inside SpagoBI\webapps\SpagoBIBirtReportEngine\WEB-INF\lib
4. Delete the POI folder from the SpagoBI\webapps\SpagoBIBirtReportEngine\WEB-INF\lib\org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.2.2.v20130216-1152.jar\org\apache\ path. 
   This can be seen when ‘Open Archive ‘ of 7 zip is used on org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.2.2.v20130216-1152.jar file.
5. To tell the BIRT engine to use this emitter modify the engine-config file of 
   SpagoBI\webapps\SpagoBIBirtReportEngine\WEB-INF\classes. You'll comment out the default emitter and add

   ```
   <XLS_EMITTER>uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.XlsEmitter</XLS_EMITTER>
   ```

**Steps to use the spudsoft emitter in BIRT designtime  / SpagoBI Studio**

1. Place the emitter jar file in SpagoBIStudio_5.0.0_win32\plugins folder of BIRT.
2. Delete the by default emitter jar file of BIRT.
3. Append the viewer property file with the below lines from C:\Program Files\SpagoBIStudio_5.0.0_win32\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer_4.2.1.v201209071804\birt\WEB-INF folder,

   ```
   viewer.extension.xlsx=xlsxviewer.label.xlsx=xlsx2007
   ```

Comment: I have the same c\version as you but I have some error in console. Aside the main purpose is to remove formatting of the excel. Anyway IO found your answer useful so I will accept it and look forward another solution - probably to write custom formatter. If you have some tip how to customize emitter please put it as a comment.

Comment: I was able to get Tribix BIRT Excel emitter working as well. No suggestions on how to customize an emitter.  However, Talend may be a better fit if you just need to extract data, without fancy formatting, and lay it out to Excel, CSV, etc. I'm switching to that approach for a particular, high-row count, multiple tab data extract going to Excel.

Comment: This is the error after trying to use spudsoft emitter ... the very same version:


org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: EmitterID uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.XlsEmitter for render option is invalid.
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.setupRenderOption(EngineTask.java:2103)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
        .......

Comment: It is not working in spagoBI.. I have done all the steps but the spagoBI is not running..

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these:

- XLSX emitter from BIRT
- Tribix XLS emitter (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tribix/)
- Arctorus emitter (https://www.arctorus.com/arctorus-birt-emitters/features)
- .ods report the plugins from birt-rcp-report-designer